# Mapping username to tweets with storm

Tags: java, twitter, apache-storm

I'm trying to create a topology that has:1 spout that emits tweets and two  bolts:
 a TweetParserBolt that collects tweets 
 and UserParserBolt that collects the tweeters' username.

Suppose I've created a third bolt that anchors the TweetParserBolt and the UserParserBolt so that it can  map the  tweeter's username to a list of tweets that she/he have already posted.The problem I've encountered is that the bolt returns a null list of tweets.

Can anyone please help me understand what's wrong with the code

Below is my code for the topology and the three bolts:

```
public class TwitterTopology {
private static String consumerKey = "*********************";
private static String consumerSecret = "*****************";
private static String accessToken = "********************";
private static String accessTokenSecret = "****************";

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{

    /*** SETUP ***/

    String remoteClusterTopologyName = null;
    if (args!=null) {
        if (args.length==1) {
            remoteClusterTopologyName = args[0];
        }
        // If credentials are provided as commandline arguments
        else if (args.length==4) {
            accessToken =args[0];
            accessTokenSecret =args[1];
            consumerKey =args[2];
            consumerSecret =args[3];
        }

    }
    /**************** ****************/

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    FilterQuery filterQuery = new FilterQuery();
    filterQuery.track(new String[]{"#cloudcomputing"});
    filterQuery.language(new String[]{"en"});

    TwitterSpout spout = new TwitterSpout( accessToken, accessTokenSecret,consumerKey, consumerSecret, filterQuery);
    builder.setSpout("TwitterSpout",spout,1);

    builder.setBolt("TweetParserBolt",new TweetParserBolt(),4).shuffleGrouping("TwitterSpout");
    builder.setBolt("UserMapperBolt",new UserParserBolt()).shuffleGrouping("TwitterSpout");

    UserAndTweetsMapperBolt()).fieldsGrouping(("TweetParserBolt"), new Fields("username","tweet","bolt"))
                                                                            .fieldsGrouping(("UserMapperBolt"),new Fields("username","tweet","bolt"));

    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(true);


    if (remoteClusterTopologyName!=null) {
        conf.setNumWorkers(4);

        StormSubmitter.submitTopology(remoteClusterTopologyName, conf, builder.createTopology());
    }
    else {
        conf.setMaxTaskParallelism(3);

        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology("test", conf, builder.createTopology());

        Thread.sleep(460000);

        cluster.shutdown();
    }


}

public class TweetParserBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
   private OutputCollector collector;

   @Override
   public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer){
      declarer.declare(new Fields("username","tweet","bolt"));
   }



   @Override
   public void prepare(Map map,TopologyContext context,OutputCollector collector){
      this.collector=collector;
   }

   @Override
   public void execute(Tuple tuple){
      Status tweet=(Status)tuple.getValue(0);
      String username=tweet.getUser().getScreenName();

      collector.emit(tuple,new Values(username,tweet,"tweet_parser_bolt"));

    }
  }

   public class UserParserBolt extends BaseRichBolt{
     private OutputCollector collector;

     @Override
     public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer){
        declarer.declare(new Fields("username","tweet"));
     }



     @Override
     public void prepare(Map map,TopologyContext context,OutputCollector collector){
        this.collector=collector;
     }

     @Override
     public void execute(Tuple tuple){
       Status tweet=(Status)tuple.getValue(0);
       String username=tweet.getUser().getScreenName();

       collector.emit(tuple,new Values(username,tweet,"user_parser_bolt"));

    }
 }

 public class UserAndTweetsMapperBolt extends  BaseRichBolt {
    private OutputCollector collector;

    List<Tuple>listOfTuples;


    Map<String,Status>tempTweetsMap;
    Map<String,List<Status>>UserAndTweetsMap;
    List<Status>tweets;
    List<String>tempUsers;


    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer){
       declarer.declare(new Fields("username","tweets"));
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map map,TopologyContext context,OutputCollector collector){
      this.collector=collector;
      this.listOfTuples=new ArrayList<Tuple>();

      this.tempTweetsMap=new HashMap<String, Status>();
      this.UserAndTweetsMap=new HashMap<String, List<Status>>();

      this.tempUsers=new ArrayList<String>();
      this.tweets=new ArrayList<Status>();
    }



    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple){
       //String username=tuple.getStringByField("username");
       //Status status=(Status)tuple.getValueByField("tweet");

       String username=tuple.getValue(0).toString();

       String sourceComponent=tuple.getSourceComponent();

       if(sourceComponent.equals("TwitterParserBolt")){
          String tempUser1=tuple.getValue(0).toString();
          Status tempStatus1=(Status)tuple.getValue(1);

          tempTweetsMap.put(tempUser1,tempStatus1);

       }else if(sourceComponent.equals("UserParserBolt")){
          String tempUser2=tuple.getValue(0).toString();
          Status tempStatus2=(Status)tuple.getValue(1);

          tempUsers.add(tempUser2);
      }


      for(int i=0;i<tempUsers.size();i++){
         for(int j=0;j<tempTweetsMap.size();j++){
             if(tempUsers.get(i).equals(tempTweetsMap.get(j).getUser().getScreenName())){
                 tweets.add(tempTweetsMap.get(j));
             }
         }
     }


        collector.emit(new Values(username,tweets));
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a fields grouping on just the username in the bolt that combines them. If you group by all the fields as you're doing now, you may or may not get all the tweets for the same user in the same task. Also, your map will only capture the last status for any given user. If you want them all you need to make the value an array of statuses.

```
UserAndTweetsMapperBolt().
    fieldsGrouping(("TweetParserBolt"), new Fields("username")).
    fieldsGrouping(("UserMapperBolt"),new Fields("username"));
```

Comment: So something like this:So something like this:
if(sourceComponent.equals("TwitterParserBolt")){
        String tempUser1=tuple.getValue(0).toString();
        Status tempStatus1=(Status)tuple.getValue(1);
        tempTweets.add(tempStatus1);

        tempTweetsMap.put(tempUser1,tempTweets);

in the 3rd bolt?

Comment: no, you need to change your topology definition. I updated the answer to reflect the correct definition